# Question/Survey Slider in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, survey

Is there any option to add sliders to Survey Sharepoint App instead of a multiple choice? I know answers can be single line, multiple choice, checkbox, etc but I prefer to use slider. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

By default, we cannot add the slider column into survey list in SharePoint online.

It is by design.

And you could consider creating custom survey in SharePoint online.

More references:

[Creating Surveys in Office 365: Microsoft Forms vs. SharePoint Survey App.](https://practical365.com/collaboration/forms/creating-surveys-office-365/)

[Can I custom a survey page layout in Sharepoint Online.](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-custom-a-survey-page-layout-in-Sharepoint-Online)